# How can I make a data structure that essentially just stores a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have written several functions that operate on a list storing keys and values in the same list, e.g.
`myList = [k1, v1, k2, v2]` but instead of operating on a list, I need to make my own data structure called Translator for my functions to operate on.

Here is one of the functions, it simply checks if a key is in the list. (I am a beginner to Haskell and am not allowed to use any functions I haven't written myself so I know there is probably a lot of room for improvement with this function but that's not what I'm looking for)

```
hasTranslation _ [] = False
hasTranslation k l = hasTranslation' k l 0
hasTranslation' k l@(x:xs) n
                         | n `mod` 2 == 1 && xs == [] = False
                         | n `mod` 2 == 1 = hasTranslation' k xs (n+1)
                         | k == x = True
                         | otherwise = hasTranslation' k xs (n+1)
```

I need to make a data structure that stores keys and values of the same type in a list type format and then amend my functions to do this.

I have tried several combinations of `type Translator a = [a]` and `data Translator = IntTranslator [Int] deriving (Show, Eq)` though have not been able to wrap my head around how to apply these to how I need them to work.

I should note that my data structure NEEDS to work for keys/values of type Int and String and anything else is a bonus.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: it has to be stored in one single list, wrap key and value into one might be an option

```
data KV k v = K k | V v deriving Show -- or use Either
type KVList k v = [KV k v]

hasTranslation :: (Eq k) => k -> KVList k v -> Bool
hasTranslation _ [] = False
hasTranslation k ((V _) : xs) = hasTranslation k xs
hasTranslation k ((K k') : xs)
  | k == k' = True
  | otherwise = hasTranslation k xs
```

---

**Old**: A direct translation might be `[(k, v)]`.

```
type KVList k v = [(k, v)]

hasTranslation :: (Eq k) => k -> KVList k v -> Bool
hasTranslation _ [] = False
hasTranslation k ((k', _) : xs)
  | k == k'   = True
  | otherwise = hasTranslation k xs
```

Comment: I must store the keys and values in one single list, it can't be a list of tuples

Comment: @DylanD.B please check the updates, is this what you mean?

Comment: With the updated version, is the intended use something like ```hasTranslation 3 [K 3, V 6, K 5, V 25]```?

Comment: yes, but you could adapt your usage as needed